# How to disable a checkbox "toggle switch" from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fairly new to css and html. I tried [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch) for creating a checkbox toggle switch. Now all I want is to disable this toggle switch say on clicking a different button 'Reset', so that it appears to be in OFF state with no background color.
I am looking for a solution in java script. Not sure if this requires any CSS to be modified. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you use `disabled` attribute for the input tag?

Comment: it will work but he needs to know how to achieve this using js… which without a framework is quite cumbersome.

Comment: I have tried something like below, which wouldn't report any error or work either. 
         document.myform.tglEnDis.disabled = true;
       AND   document.getElementById("tglEnDis").setAttribute("disabled", "true");

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can disable any input item using the `setAttribute("disabled", true)` function

for instance, the following will disable all the inputs of the page:

```
const allInputs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));
allInputs.forEach((input)=>{input.setAttribute("disabled", true)})
```

In your case considering you named your input using an id as follow:

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked id="yourSwitch">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

you can toggle the disable attribute using this:

```
document.getElementById("yourSwitch").toggleAttribute("disabled");
```

or simply disable it forever…

```
document.getElementById("yourSwitch").setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

here you have it

You simply give the input an id ant the rest will happen by it self

```js
document.getElementById("switch1").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("switch2").disabled = true;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked id='switch1'>
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked id='switch2'>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

As you see the second toggle is disabled

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my question. By disable i mean , the second toggle to look greyed out [like it is in the OFF state.].

Comment: @shwink `input:checked:not([disabled]) + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
`

Comment: Not familiar with this syntax. When i try this ` $('input:checked:not([disabled]) + .slider { background-color: #2196F3; }); ` , get a Syntax error, unrecognized expression:. It reports no error without ".slider"
 Is there anything similar i could try in a javascript function ?

Comment: $('.slider').css('background-color', '#ccc'); does change the color but makes it a permanent background color. Also can i get for a specific object by using id ?